# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa44bef0

Tags: ios, slider

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISlider
>   setPopUpViewCornerRadius:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xa44bef0'

**Code:**

```
self.slider1.maximumValue = 255.0;
self.slider1.popUpViewCornerRadius = 25.0;
[self.slider1 setMaxFractionDigitsDisplayed:0];
self.slider1.popUpViewColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.55 saturation:0.8 brightness:0.9 alpha:0.7];
self.slider1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:22];
self.slider1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.55 saturation:1.0 brightness:0.5 alpha:1];
```

Please guide me, Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you calling `setPopUpViewCornerRadius()` from anywhere?

Comment: @iDev Did you read the code? It's the 2nd line.

Comment: @iDev Yes, i'm using custom slider

Comment: [https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/asvaluetrackingslider]

Comment: @VNJ You are not using a custom slider. The error clearly indicates you are using `UISlider`. Perhaps you need to specify the actual class name in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are allocating self.slider you need to use `ASValueTrackingSlider` instead of `UISlider`.

if you are using story board or xib you need to give `ASValueTrackingSlider` in identity inspector. like [image]

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ASValueTrackingSlider/0.9.2/Classes/ASValueTrackingSlider.html refer the link.

Answer (score 1):

[UISlider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't have this property `popUpViewCornerRadius`, because of that this error is occurring. You will need to remove this below line.

```
self.slider1.popUpViewCornerRadius = 25.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

UiSlider does not have this property of

```
popUpViewCornerRadius
```

Either remove this line else this property would be included in the Custom class.

So change the `UISlider *slider1` to `ASValueTrackingSlider *slider1`